# Hash Parsing with Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the array of hash as shown below:

```
@line_statuses = [
  {:name=>"1", :status=>"online"},
  {:name=>"2", :status=>"online"}
]
```

I'd like to parse each hash inside of `@line_statuses` array so that I can print out the name and status as shown below.

```
1: online
2: online
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically your `@line_statuses` variable is an array, so what you have is an array of hashes. In Ruby, to iterate over an array we use the `.each` method. Then, in each iteration, we can access the values of the hash using the defined keys:

```
@line_statuses.each do |hash|
  puts hash[:name]
  puts hash[:status]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

So simple...:

```
@line_statuses.each do |line_status|
  puts "#{line_status[:name]}: #{line_status[:status]}"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

try `@line_statuses.each{|i| puts i[:name],i[:status]}`

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple:

```
@line_statuses.each { |line_status| puts "#{line_status[:name]}: #{line_status[:status]}" }
```